# Variable declared inside a for loop. How do I make this to a compile time error?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, scope

Today I investigated a logical bug in our software and figured out that this is related to the way VB.NET thread variables inside a loop.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
    Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    For Each number As Integer In numbers

        Dim isEven As Boolean

        If number Mod 2 = 0 Then
            isEven = True
        End If

        If isEven Then
            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString() & " is Even")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString() & " is Odd")
        End If

    Next
```

produces the following output

```
1 is Odd
2 is Even
3 is Even
4 is Even
5 is Even
```

The problem is that `isEven` is declared but not assigned.
In this specific case, it would be correct to write `dim isEven as Boolean = false` but I haven't done this.

In VB.NET, a variable that is declared inside a for loop keeps its value for the next itaration. This is by design: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vblanguage/thread/c9cb4c22-d40b-49ff-b535-19d47e4db38d but this is also dangerous pitfall for programmers.

However, until now, I haven't been aware of this problem/behaviour. Until now.
Most of our code base is C# anyway, which doesn't allow the use of an uninitialized variable, so there is no problem.

But we have some legacy code that is written in VB.NET that we have to support.

I don't think that anyone of our dev team has ever used this with purpose. If I explicitly want to share a variable over iterations inside a for loop, I declare it outside the scope.

So the best thing would be to generate a warning or even an error in this specific case.
But even with Option Explicit / Option Strict this does not generate a warning / an error.

Is there a way make this a compile time error or maybe a way to check this with FxCop?

Comment: "this is related to the way VB.NET thread variables inside a loop" : Nope. Your code is just wrong, it doesn't comply to the very basic programming rule : initialize your variables.

Comment: I know that my code was wrong, I didn't complain about VB, I was asking for a way to avoid this mistake in the future and find code in my legacy codebase that could be affected by this. The compiler warns me if I use a iteration variable inside a lambda expression http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763133.aspx which is a similar pitfall: The language does what it is told to do, but that is propably not what the programmer intended.

Comment: yep, got bit by this before. I think most people add an initializer and forget about it. I find it annoying.

Comment: People - OP is not looking for improvements to the code - he wants to trap this in a compiler so the software doesn't leave the factory with flaws.

Comment: +1 Exactly, Since this one time I have never found another code fragement like this in our software but I am afraid there will be similar traps in our legacy code.

Comment: "VB doesn't work like c#" does *NOT* constitute a "dangerous pitfall for programmers".  It does however constitute a requirement for professional competence.  If this is a real concern, then I would suggest paying attention to the "uninitiated variables" warnings.

Comment: The point was that, until I stumpled upon this, I belived the variable would be false for every loop, now I know better and can avoid this. My question was more like "Is there a way to find similar places that I can double check for possible mistakes".

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think that anyone of our dev team has ever used this with purpose. If I explicitly want to share a variable over iterations inside a for loop, I declare it outside the scope.

I suppose the whole point of declaring a variable inside the loop is to explicitly restrict its scope to that block, though.  To make this a compile time error would remove block-level scope from the language. While there are certainly cases where method level scope is sensible there can no doubt also be a case made for the importance of block level scope.  I don't think you can easily excise this from the language without introducing some new syntactic method for employing it.  At this point you are entering the realm of redesigning VB.NET - I'm not sure that there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: I don't want to restrict declaring a variable inside a loop I wan't to restrict declaring a variable inside a loop without initialising it. This should be allowed `dim someValue as Integer = 0` but this shouldn't `dim someValue as Integer` because the latter introduces a pontential danger because it remembers if last assigned value in the next itaration.

Comment: Yes, but part of the functionality comes from not having to initialize it.  Declaring it inside a block to have the variable block scoped just so happens to involve running over the line on each iteration.  To do what you suggest would remove the functionality of having a block scoped variable whose value can be carried across loop iterations.  It means removing functionality from the language which has no other syntax that exposes it.

Comment: Well, the thing is that VB.NET hat some ability to change the compile time behaviour, as C# does: http://aurigroup.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/figure-4.png    So I don't want to break anything, I want to configure the compiler. Besides that, if that is not possible, a FxCop rule would be a solution, too. But default FxCop does not recognize this as a problem.

Comment: So the real question is *How do I go about creating a rule for FxCop that detects uninitialised varables below method scope?*

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below.  If not allowing a declaration without an initialization is a compiler error, then this code would not produce the correct output (a running total of even numbers).  If you force me to initialize the value of 'total', then the method can never be correct.

```
Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10}
For Each number As Integer In numbers

    Dim total As Integer

    Dim isEven As Boolean = (number Mod 2 = 0)

    If isEven Then
        total += number
        Console.WriteLine("Running Total: {0}", total)
    End If
Next
```

Instead of adding an error, just fix the logic in the code.  I don't see this as a particularly dangerous pitfall.  Most programmers would be able to recognize this issue, and unit testing should also help to uncover these types of issues.

Comment: `Most programmers would be able to recognize this issue` - to be honest, I didn't. In your example I would have written `dim total as integer` between `dim numbers...` and `For Each` because I expected total to be resetet to 0 for every iteration. You wrote `Instead of adding an error, just fix the logic in the code`, that is exactly what I want to do. I fixed the problematic code, but I want to know where else in our legacy code this could introduce a bug.

Comment: @SchlaWiener one could equally argue that declaring `total` outside of the `For Each` block, in complex code, introduces the risk of being able to manipulate `total` outside of the scope of the block for which it is intended to be used.  Declaring it inside the block forces its scope to be restricted to the `For Each` block.  In cases where `total` is not needed outside of the `For Each` block it would probably be considered best practice to declare it inside the block and not outside for that reason alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you think this may be a problem with your codebase or your programmers, in your coding style specify that all uninitialised variables are declared at the start of the routine. This had been a common style guideline (especially for VB) until the prevalence of type inference.

Of course it doesn't avoid the problem, just makes it more obvious.