# .NET - Block level scope

Tags: vb.net

Please have a look at the code below:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public TestProperty As Integer
End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, 
                           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        For j = 0 To 2
            For i = 0 To 10
                Dim k As Integer
                Dim tc As TestClass
                tc = New TestClass
                tc.TestProperty = tc.TestProperty + 1
                k = k + 1
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

There is a new object (called `tc`) created on every iteration of the FOR loop, so `tc.TestProperty` is always `1`.  Why is this not the case with variable `k` i.e. the value of `k` increments by one on every iteration? I realise this is probably to do with how value types and reference types are dealt with, but I wanted to check.

Comment: Because you don't initalize `k` to `k + 1`. You initialize it to `i + 1`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, I have changed i+1 to k+1.

Comment: Ok, with this edit I'm now *very* curious about the answer to this

Comment: with your edit, your observed behavior should be gone.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, I can confirm that the observed behaviour has not gone away.

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886465/variable-declared-inside-a-for-loop-how-do-i-make-this-to-a-compile-time-error

Answer (score 1):

It's because when something is defined as block level it applies to the entire block level, regardless of loops. normally with control logic like an IF block statement the scope starts and ends and no code lines repeat.

Inside a loop structure the variable is defined inside that block, even though the Dim statement appears to be called multiple times it is not, it is not actually an executable statement (just a definition and reservation of a placeholder as mentioned above in one comment)

To cause it to behave in the same way as "tc" you also need to initialize it in a similar way. (the assignment to 0 would occur each loop, not the definition)

```
Dim k As Integer = 0
```

Alternately if you change how your dealing with tc it would behave the same way as k where it is in block scope the entire time inside the loop. In the below example tc is not redefined each loop either.

```
Dim tc as TestClass
if tc is nothing then tc = New TestClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to `Dim k As Integer = 0` to keep it at 1.

This is because `Dim k As Integer` [retains it's value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), while `Dim k As Integer = 0` "declares and initializes" it.

Specifically: "If you alter the value but then return to the Dim statement, your altered value is replaced by the value supplied in the Dim statement."

Actually, I don't know why it doesn't seem go out of scope. Maybe without the `New` keyword it's using the same block of memory.

Comment: Thnaks.  I don't understand what you mean by: "If you alter the value but then return to the Dim statement, your altered value is replaced by the value supplied in the Dim statement."

Answer (score 0):

As implied by the title of this question, you're querying the scope versus the lifetime of the variable.

The scope of the local variables `k` and `tc` is the inner `For` loop. The lifetime is the whole of the `Sub`.

If you adjusted the `tc = New TestClass` to `If tc Is Nothing Then tc = New TestClass` (and ignored the warning that causes), you should then see the `tc.TestProperty` increment too.

Answer (score 0):

"Dim k As Integer" isn't actually translate into any code except "space reservation" (that is surely made at compile time). So the application does not pass on that sentence 10 times.

As a matter of proof, you **can not put** a trace bullet on that line of code !

On the other hand, your code create on each loop a fresh new object TestClass (holding a brand new variable "TestProperty) and assign it to the variable "tc". The previous object is lost and carbage collected anytime soon.