# Uninitialized integer not resetting in each iteration of the loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

### Problem

I am testing the following simple VB.Net code:

```
  For i = 0 To 5
     Dim f As Integer
     If i = 3 Then
        f = 1
     End If
     Debug.WriteLine(f)
  Next
```

and the output is as follows:

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
```

but i was expecting:

```
0
0
0
1
0
0
```

### Solution

The simple way to solve it is to replace `Dim f As Integer` by `Dim f As Integer = 0`

### Question

Is this the expected behavior and if so why?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9886465/4934172

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in the [Visual Basic Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope):

> Even if the scope of a variable is limited to a block, its lifetime is still that of the entire procedure. If you enter the block more than once during the procedure, each block variable retains its previous value. To avoid unexpected results in such a case, it is wise to initialize block variables at the beginning of the block.

That precisely describes the behaviour you're seeing.

I don't know *why* the language was designed that way - I prefer a language that doesn't let you use a variable without it being definitely assigned a value - but I wouldn't be surprised if it's just a matter of history and backward compatibility at this stage.